# sort out IP addrs from file in C program

Tags: c, file, clang, logic, getline

So, I have to create a .c file which sorts out IP addresses in ascending order and gives a count to all ip adresses. Considering there is ip.txt file present while has content like below (IP Address and ErrorCode)

```
127.0.0.0 500
127.0.0.0 400
127.0.0.1 300
127.0.0.2 100
```

Please suggest something If you're good with Programming, Advance Thanks!

Below is trial that I performed, Feel free to suggest and modify code for perfect output.

Tried code is attached in Image file, I'm expecting to sort out IP addresses and give count of IP addresses from Max to Min in output console.

File_Operation_Code Below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int count=0, totalCh=0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("ip.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("IP File does not exist!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        count++;
        totalCh+=read;
        printf("line of length: %zu\n", read);
        printf("line content: %s", line);
    }

    printf("Total number of lines=%d\n", count);
    printf("Total number of characters=%d\n", totalCh);

    // logic to fetch IP addr and sort out and give count to output console pending

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: @ewokx code attched, please help if you can

Comment: Where is your code that tries to do this? We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: Since the file has fixed format, all you need to do is split each line at the space character. You can use `strtok()` or `strchr()` for this.

Comment: @Barmar I tried it by structure reading but couldn't work, I am not able to think of any solution, Please suggest something If you can

Comment: Just use `sscanf(line, "%s %d", ipaddr, &code);`

Comment: It doesn't look like you tried very hard to solve your problem (no sort).  The problem description doesn't call for a character count.  Do you ignore the error code with respect to the output?   Is it only ipv4 or could you have ipv6, too?  If you don't have to read the input from a file then reading it from stdin is more flexible.

Comment: Also, the problem description is not very good.  In first section it's "sorts out IP addresses in ascending order and gives a count to all ip adresses." and later you say "sort out IP addresses and give count of IP addresses from Max to Min in output console."  Which is it?  Do you want a count per IP address?  I assume so otherwise there is little point in sorting but you don't say.

Comment: I suggest you: 1. filter (that is remove records outside range of interest; consider using half-intervals for your ip range with inclusive start and exclusive end), 2. project (i.e. remove error code), 3. sort (`qsort()`), 4. count number of records per IP.

Comment: Use SQlite if this isn't homework.  You can import the data without code and the output is simple select query.

Comment: You did not even tried to sort or test anything...

Comment: @arfneto I had tried many logics from my end, but it didn't work as expected output, hence i did not posted those wrong logics here

Comment: Well, consider the way I showed you: A single loop to extract valid lines, a function to compare records in a single place, sort records as they are read. It is an easy way, worked at the 1st  time and is trivial to adapt. Good luck! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a suitable compare function, then you can just use `qsort` to sort the data.

But you may not need even this. Below is an example of a way to go from the file to the result in a safe way.

#### IPv4 address for a host

An IP (v4) address is a group of 4 octets. For a host you can not have `0` as the 1st octet or for the last one. Also you can not have all ones --- `255`. `0` is the network address and `255` is the broadcast address.

#### encapsulating: a `Packet` for a valid IP and code

```
typedef struct
{
    char     ip[16];
    int      a, b, c, d;  // octets
    unsigned code;
} Packet;
```

This is ok for a rapid test and makes life easier. Since this is just toy we can have both the string and the decimal values for the octets.

This function `so_compare()` compares 2 `Packet` and return `-1` if `one` comes before `other` in sorting order. And `+1` if `one` goes after `other`. This is all you need to sort them using `qsort` from stdlib in `C`.

```
int so_compare(Packet* one, Packet* other)
{
    if (one == NULL) return 0;
    if (other == NULL) return 0;
    // 1
    if (one->a < other->a) return -1;
    if (one->a > other->a) return 1;
    // 2
    if (one->b < other->b) return -1;
    if (one->b > other->b) return 1;
    // 3
    if (one->c < other->c) return -1;
    if (one->c > other->c) return 1;
    // 4
    if (one->d < other->d) return -1;
    if (one->d > other->d) return 1;
    // code
    if (one->code < other->code) return -1;
    if (one->code > other->code) return 1;
    // stable
    return 1;
}
```

And you just need to get one for each valid line in the input file.

#### validating a line

This can be very simple: we just need a *valid* IP and a valid code. `sscanf()` is good here, since we can parse all  5 values at once.

#### a simple function to parse a line

`so_get_packet()` below takes a line from the input file and returns a valid `Packet`, in a few lines of code.

Extracts the values for the octets, validates them, fills in a new `Packet` and we are done.

```
Packet* so_get_packet(const char* addr)
{
    int         a, b, c, d;
    int         code;
    int         res  = 0;
    const char* mask = "%3d.%3d.%3d.%3d %3d";
    res = sscanf(addr, mask, &a, &b, &c, &d, &code);
    if (res != 5) return NULL;
    if ((a < 1) || (a > 254)) return NULL;
    if ((b < 0) || (b > 254)) return NULL;
    if ((c < 0) || (c > 254)) return NULL;
    if ((d < 1) || (d > 254)) return NULL;
    Packet* pck = malloc(sizeof(Packet));
    if (pck == NULL) return NULL;
    sprintf(pck->ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a, b, c, d);
    pck->a = a, pck->b = b, pck->c = c, pck->d = d;
    pck->code = code;
    return pck;
}
```

#### storing valid packets

This is `C`. Life is easier with composition and containment. Consider a sequence of packets and we can use `Vector` as below to store them.

```
#define MAX_DATA 100
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    Packet data[MAX_DATA];
} Vector;
```

So the program is just a matter of

- read the file
- create a `Packet` for each valid line data
- inserting packets into a `Vector` thing
- sorting the data

As each `Vector` has a `size` we always know the number of addresses we got so far.

#### no need to *`qsort`*  the data

Since we get one line at a time makes more sense to just insert them in order...

```
int so_insert(Packet* pck, Vector* V)
{
    if (pck == NULL) return -1;
    if (V == NULL) return -2;
    if (V->size == V->limit) return -3; // full
    if (V->size == 0) // was empty
    {
        V->data[0] = *pck;
        V->size = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    for (size_t pos = V->size; pos > 0; --pos)
    {   // insert in position
        if (so_compare(pck, &V->data[pos - 1]) > 0)
        {   // 'pos' is the position
            V->data[pos] = *pck;
            ++V->size;
            return 0;
        }
        V->data[pos] = V->data[pos - 1];
    };  // for
    V->data[0] = *pck;
    ++V->size;
    return 0;
}
```

No surprise here: `so_insert()` as above inserts a `Packet` into a `Vector`, in order, so when we reach the end on input all lines are already sorted in `Vector`.

#### consuming a file

This `so_consume_file()` does the expected: gets a file name and returns a sorted list of addresses and codes. Or `NULL` in case of error.

```
Vector* so_consume_file(const char* file_name)
{
    FILE* in = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return NULL;
    // create array
    Vector* data = so_create(MAX_DATA);
    if (data == NULL) return NULL;

    char  buffer[256] = {0};
    char* p           = buffer;
    int   res         = 0;
    while ((p = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in)) != NULL)
    {
        Packet* pck = so_get_packet(buffer);
        if (pck != NULL)
        {
            so_insert(pck, data);
            free(pck);
        }
    };
    fclose(in);
    so_show_v(data, "final data ");
    return data;
}
```

And is easy to read: a single loop. If a line has a packet it gets into the list. At the end the list is printed and destroyed.

#### full code for a test

```
#define MAX_DATA 100

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char     ip[16];
    int      a, b, c, d;  // octets
    unsigned code;
} Packet;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    Packet data[MAX_DATA];
} Vector;

Vector* so_create(size_t);
Vector* so_destroy(Vector*);
Vector* so_consume_file(const char*);
int so_insert(Packet*, Vector*);
int     so_show_v(Vector*,const char*);

Packet* so_get_packet(const char*);
int     so_compare(Packet*, Packet*);
int     so_show_p(Packet*, const char*);

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597529/
// sort-out-ip-addrs-from-file-in-c-program

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* def_name = "in.txt";
    char        f_name[50];
    if (argc < 2)
        strcpy(f_name, def_name);
    else { strcpy(f_name, argv[1]); }
    fprintf(stderr, "input file is \"%s\"\n", f_name);
    Vector* my_data = so_consume_file(f_name);
    so_destroy(my_data);
    return 0;
}

Vector* so_create(size_t limit)
{
    if (limit > MAX_DATA) return NULL;
    Vector* one = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->limit = limit;
    one->size  = 0;
    return one;
}

Vector* so_destroy(Vector* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;
    free(del);
    return NULL;
}

Vector* so_consume_file(const char* file_name)
{
    FILE* in = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return NULL;
    // create array
    Vector* data = so_create(MAX_DATA);
    if (data == NULL) return NULL;

    char  buffer[256] = {0};
    char* p           = NULL;
    while ((p = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in)) != NULL)
    {
        Packet* pck = so_get_packet(buffer);
        if (pck != NULL)
        {
            so_insert(pck, data);
            free(pck);
        }
    };
    fclose(in);
    so_show_v(data, "final data ");
    return data;
}

int so_insert(Packet* pck, Vector* V)
{
    if (pck == NULL) return -1;
    if (V == NULL) return -2;
    if (V->size == V->limit) return -3; // full
    if (V->size == 0) // was empty
    {
        V->data[0] = *pck;
        V->size = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    for (size_t pos = V->size; pos > 0; --pos)
    {   // insert in position
        if (so_compare(pck, &V->data[pos - 1]) > 0)
        {   // 'pos' is the position
            V->data[pos] = *pck;
            ++V->size;
            return 0;
        }
        V->data[pos] = V->data[pos - 1];
    };  // for
    V->data[0] = *pck;
    ++V->size;
    return 0;
}

int so_show_v(Vector* V, const char* msg) 
{
    if (V == NULL) return -1; // no vector
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%llu/%llu elements\n", V->size, V->limit);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V->size; ++i)
    {
        so_show_p(&V->data[i], NULL);
    }
    printf("---\n\n");
    return 0;
}

Packet* so_get_packet(const char* addr)
{
    int         a, b, c, d;
    int         code;
    int         res  = 0;
    const char* mask = "%3d.%3d.%3d.%3d %3d";
    res = sscanf(addr, mask, &a, &b, &c, &d, &code);
    if (res != 5) return NULL;
    if ((a < 1) || (a > 254)) return NULL;
    if ((b < 0) || (b > 254)) return NULL;
    if ((c < 0) || (c > 254)) return NULL;
    if ((d < 1) || (d > 254)) return NULL;
    Packet* pck = malloc(sizeof(Packet));
    if (pck == NULL) return NULL;
    sprintf(pck->ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a, b, c, d);
    pck->a = a, pck->b = b, pck->c = c, pck->d = d;
    pck->code = code;
    return pck;
}

int so_compare(Packet* one, Packet* other)
{
    if (one == NULL) return 0;
    if (other == NULL) return 0;
    // 1
    if (one->a < other->a) return -1;
    if (one->a > other->a) return 1;
    // 2
    if (one->b < other->b) return -1;
    if (one->b > other->b) return 1;
    // 3
    if (one->c < other->c) return -1;
    if (one->c > other->c) return 1;
    // 4
    if (one->d < other->d) return -1;
    if (one->d > other->d) return 1;
    // code
    if (one->code < other->code) return -1;
    if (one->code > other->code) return 1;
    // stable
    return 1;
}

int so_show_p(Packet* P, const char* msg)
{
    if (P == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("     %16s %4d\n", P->ip, P->code);
    return 0;
}
```

The program accepts a file name as input. Default is *in.txt*

#### example output

```
SO> cat in.txt

stack overflow

127.0.0.0 500 not a host
127.0.0.0 400 not a host
127.0.0.1 300
127.0.0.2 100
127.0.0.2 99
127.0.0.2 101
127.0.0.2 100

SO> v1
input file is "in.txt"
final data 5/100 elements
            127.0.0.1  300
            127.0.0.2   99
            127.0.0.2  100
            127.0.0.2  100
            127.0.0.2  101
---


SO>

SO>


SO> cat other.txt
127.0.0.10 500
127.0.0.100 400
127.0.0.1 300
127.0.0.2 100
127.0.0.2 101
127.0.0.2 101
10.0.0.1 200
10.0.0.1 201
10.0.0.92 200
10.0.0.2 200

SO> v1 other.txt
input file is "other.txt"
final data 10/100 elements
             10.0.0.1  200
             10.0.0.1  201
             10.0.0.2  200
            10.0.0.92  200
            127.0.0.1  300
            127.0.0.2  100
            127.0.0.2  101
            127.0.0.2  101
           127.0.0.10  500
          127.0.0.100  400
---


SO>
```

Not really tested. Hope it helps as showing a way to go from the raw file data to a prototype in a controlled way.

Comment: This works great almost, The point you misunderstood is Sorting means whichever IP is highest in file (for example 127.0.0.2 is 10 times which is highest) that IP needs to be shown first, and which ever is lowest needs to be shown last, likewise in order. Still, this is a good solution, Thanks for your efforts man!

Comment: Did you read the code? The sorting criteria is used in a single point, in `so_compare()`. It was my choice to use this way, also my choice to ignore network addresses. I used: (1) ascending order (2) ascending order of code if IP is the same (3) preserve order if IP and code are equal. The compare function must just return -1 if the 1st arg must come before and +1 if it must come afer the 2nd. e.g. for descending order of IP just invert -1 and +1... This was just to show you a controlled way of approaching the problem.